# How to Implement MongoDB Authentication in docker-compose?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have an application that uses docker-compose with MongoDB (version 4). My application is working perfectly, but I'm having trouble configuring authentication in MongoDB.

I created a .env file in my project and defined some environment variables to set up authentication in MongoDB. Here are the variables I used in the .env file:

```
MONGO_USER="my_user"
MONGO_PASSWORD="my_pass"
MONGO_DB="my_db"
```

However, it seems that these environment variables are not taking effect.

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nodejs-app:
    image: node:16
    container_name: nodejs-container
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    command: 
      - sh
      - -c
      - |
        npm install && npm start

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:4
    container_name: mongodb-container
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/data/db
```

How can I correctly implement authentication in MongoDB within my docker-compose.yml file?

I use a server with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the example of mongo image in docker hub
https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo

```
 mongodb:
image: mongo:4
container_name: mongodb-container
environment:
  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
ports:
  - "27017:27017"
volumes:
  - ./data/db:/data/db
```